# Plotting labels as points in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following:

```
> x<-runif(20)
> y<-rnorm(x)
> g<-rep(factor(LETTERS[1:4]),5)
```

How can I do

```
> plot(x,y)
```

so that the points that are plotted is the corresponding value of `g`?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend `ggplot`. See @BenBolker's solution below. Josh's is the quickest though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
plot(x,y,type="n")
text(x,y,as.character(g))
```

or (obligatory ggplot)

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x,y,g)
qplot(x,y,label=g,geom="text",data=d)
```

or (lattice)

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(y~x,
    panel=function(...) { 
       panel.xyplot(...,type="n")
       panel.text(x,y,g) })
```

(I don't know how well that last solution would work if one actually wanted to use some of the features of lattice like dividing the plot into multiple panels ...)

Answer (score 6):

For a one-line solution, use the `pch` (i.e. 'plotting character') argument:

```
plot(x,y,pch=as.character(g))
```

Comment: This occurred to me after I posted my answer, but will only work for one-character labels ...

Comment: @BenBolker -- Yeah, yours is definitely the better/more general solution. Also, it's good to remind folks of the plot `type="n"` option.